# Grails: Building an Application for an existing Database. How to generate fitting Domainclasses

Tags: grails, firebird, firebird1.5

i got an old Firebird Database with a lot of content.
Is there an easy way to get the content of this Database without rewriting the tables from Database for an Grails Application?

An example would be nice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRAG is a very nice Tool..but it does not fit for Firebird Databases.

Well i just rebuild my Tables and everything works fine. I think this is the best Solution to keep it nice and clean.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [GRAG](http://grag.sourceforge.net).

From their homepage:

> You can use The GRails Application
>   Generator (GRAG) to get started with
>   Grails using an existing database. It
>   will generate Grails domain objects
>   including constraints and relations.
>   After generating the domain objects,
>   you can continue using Grails with all
>   it's power.

Comment: GRAG does not support FirebirdSQL Mapping. You can manually add Drivers for JDBC but correct Mapping is not available.

Comment: You could try to export the Firebird data into another database which is support by GRAG. Then generate your domain classes with GRAG. The generated classes should work on the Firebird database as well.